# converting string to int: Python

Tags: python

I have a Series Dataobject which have dtype as object.
It contains int in str format as well as many strings. I want to convert only int to int type and del rest.

Example:

```
'1','3','sd34','4','r5'
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Where is the Python in your question?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple one-liner.

```
output = [int(s) for s in data_list if s.isdecimal()]
```

You may also use a generator expression in case the dataset is large. This will be much more memory efficient for a single iteration over the data.

```
output_gen = (int(s) for s in data_list if s.isdecimal())
```

Last option, if you wish to be extremely efficient, is to use full C-level iterators:

```
output_gen = map(int, filter(str.isdecimal, data_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data = ['1','3','sd34','4','r5']
result = []

for d in data:
    try:
        result.append(int(d))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: 'Flat is better than nested.' ; 'Errors should never pass silently.'. You're capturing all errors, and it's nested for no reason. Ctrl+C here will not work to interrupt the code for example in a long dataset. `import this` mate